# Want to display a default data from API as soon as page opens before any input by user?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js, use-effect

#### Intro

I am fetching data from `openweatherAPI` and it is being shown in the console and page also.

#### Problem

But I am not able to display the default data on the front end as soon as the page opens for the first time (`before inputting any value and click`)? Although after inputting the value and click, I am able to display the data for that city.

#### What I want ?

I am able to display `data.day` and `data.week` but what I want that as soon as the page opens it should display default data (of any city like Delhi). That means I had to call the API again through `useEffect`. But it is not working.

#### Code

```
import Head from "next/head";
import {useEffect} from 'react';
import Image from "next/image";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Today_highlight from "./components/Today_highlight";
import Weather_Today from "./components/Weather_Today";
import Weather_week from "./components/Weather_week";
import searchimageurl from "../public/search.gif";



export default function Home() {
  //console.log("res1 = ", results1);
  const router = useRouter();
  const [city, setCity] = useState("");
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    day:{},week:{}
  });

  useEffect(() => {
  
    async function apiCallFunction() {
      const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Delhi&appid=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY_1}`;
      const res = await fetch(url);
      const data1 = await res.json();
      console.log(data1);
  
      //api-2
      const url1 = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Delhi&appid=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY_1}`;
      const res1 = await fetch(url1);
      const data2 = await res1.json();
      console.log(data2);
      //return {data,data1}
      setData({ day: data1, week: data2 });
    }
  }, [])
  

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setCity(e.target.value);
    //console.log(city)
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    //console.log("%c ClickSubmit","font-size:12px; color:green; padding:10px;")
    console.log("city = ", city);
    //router.push(`/?term=${city}`);

    const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY_1}`;
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const data1 = await res.json();
    console.log(data1);

    //api-2
    const url1 = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=${city}&appid=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY_1}`;
    const res1 = await fetch(url1);
    const data2 = await res1.json();
    console.log(data2);
    //return {data,data1}
    setData({ day: data1, week: data2 });
  };

  const kelvinToCelcius = (temp) => {
    return (temp - 273.15).toPrecision(3) + "°";
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Weather-Lytics</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      {/* input */}
      <div className="p-3 xl:p-10 flex flex-row justify-center items-center space-x-2 xl:space-x-5 bg-blue-900">
        <div className="bg-lime-300 border-2 border-stone-700 rounded-full ">
          <input
            className="w-full rounded-full p-2 xl:p-4 text-base xl:text-3xl text-blue-800 font-bold active:rounded-full "
            value={city}
            placeholder="Enter city"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button className="p-1 m-auto p-auto" onClick={() => handleSubmit()}>
            <div className="w-14 h-14 xl:w-16 xl:h-16 p-2 rounded-full bg-pink-400 border-2 hover:bg-pink-600 border-white">
              <Image
                src={searchimageurl}
                layout="responsive"
                alt="Search_icon"
                className=" rounded-full p-3 bg-blue-900 "
              />
            </div>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="min-h-full bg-red-400 flex flex-col lg:flex-row">
        <div className="bg-blue-300 w-full lg:w-1/4 lg:h-full">
          <Weather_Today results={data.day} kelvinToCelcius={kelvinToCelcius} />
        </div>
        <div className="bg-green-500 w-full lg:h-full ">
          <div className="min-h-full flex flex-col">
            <div className="bg-yellow-400 w-full">
              <Today_highlight
                results={data.day}
                kelvinToCelcius={kelvinToCelcius}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="bg-orange-600 w-full">
              <Weather_week
                results1={data.week}
                kelvinToCelcius={kelvinToCelcius}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

// export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
//   // if there is no query
//   if (!query.term) query.term = "Bhopal";

//   //api-1
//   const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${query.term}&appid=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY_1}`;
//   const res = await fetch(url);
//   const data = await res.json();
//   //console.log(data);

//   //api-2
//   const url1 = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=${query.term}&appid=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY_1}`;
//   const res1 = await fetch(url1);
//   const data1 = await res1.json();
//   //console.log(data1);

//   return {
//     props: {
//       results: data,
//       results1: data1,
//     },
//   };
// }
```

I don't want to give a default value `Delhi` to the

```
const [city,setCity] = useState('Delhi')
```

because this value will also be there displayed in the input all the time as soon as no one input the text?

#### How to do so?

Comment: Have you tried initialising the `data` state variable with the data you get from `getServerSideProps`? E.g. `const [data, setData] = useState({ day: result, week: result1 });`

Comment: No but this option looks tempting

Answer (score 1):

Where you define the `url` you could conditionally set the city value try this:

```
const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city || 'Delhi'}&appid=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY_1}`;

const url1 = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=${city || 'Delhi'}&appid=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY_1}`;
```

This way if `city` has a value it will take the city value if not it will take `Delhi`.

Comment: But This is not working because if I put the `||` condition in handleSubmit, then it will run after clicking the button and also if I put this condition in useEffect, it is already not working.